# Concatenate string to Display Culture Value MVC 4+

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, internationalization, asp.net-mvc-5, resx

Hi I've followed the following post in order to localize labels for a form.

http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx

I works perfectly but I'm trying to find a way to concatenate ":" on to the display value (i.e. Address:)?

View:

```
<div class="col-sm-5">
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address)
</div>
```

Model:

```
 [Required]
 [Display(Name = "Address", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]
 public string Name { get; set; }
```

key in resx file

```
Name :Address
Value:Address
```

My attempts are:

Change the model

```
[Display(Name = "Address" + ":", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]
```

Change the view

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, Name + ":")
```

Anyone with any ideas if it's possible? Is there away to get the Name property and manipulate it in the view?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer to keep it simple and see the View changed by adding, for example, `&#58;`.

The text "Address" is bound to be used somewhere else where a colon or dash isn't required.

Comment: Exactly what I should be doing! Thanks. I have no idea why I was trying to make it so complicated!